# create a new local string variable from value of another variable?

Tags: android, variables

Is is possible to create an new local variable from value of another?

e.g. if value of var1 = "button1" can I construct a new local variable like button1type, ie.using the value of var1 to make part of the new variable

Comment: I think that's not possible in languages like Java.

Comment: Where do you need this for? I think there will probably be a better solution for your problem.

Comment: Depending on which button I press, I pass a value via extras and then using this need to make variable names to write to correct col in database. I can just use switch, case and have separate update database sql. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
String foo = "ohai_" + var1; // Would be "ohai_button1"
```

If you mean *name* the variable based on the value in `var1`? No, but you don't need to.

If you need to associate data based on a string (or other) value, consider using a map.

Comment: @user1095784 I mean *a* map, `HashMap` is one implementation, and a typical choice.